# Bat file auto update air native application without showing cmd

Tags: java, c, windows, batch-file, air

I need to make an auto silent update for an AIR desktop application that uses a native extension, (a native signed installer that is not supported by the air Updater class) I followed this [conversation](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/688450), so now I have a bat file that uninstall, install and launch the application which works perfectly,

```
taskkill /IM Project.exe
taskkill /IM adl.exe
wmic product where name="Project" call uninstall /nointeractive
"%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\com.Project\Local Store\Project.exe" -silent -eulaAccepted -location "\"%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\" -desktopShortcut
"%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Project\Project.exe"
taskkill /IM cmd.exe
```

I have made a java program that run it, and that works fine too, even better than I expected, It doesnt even show the cmd, and perfectly silent,

```
try {
        String ls_str;

        Process ls_proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Bat/update.bat");

        // get its output (your input) stream

        DataInputStream ls_in = new DataInputStream(
                                          ls_proc.getInputStream());

        try {
        while ((ls_str = ls_in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(ls_str);
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        System.exit(0);
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        System.err.println(e1);
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

But I can't really implement this java solution, AIR does not support that

So I made a native extension that will launch the .bat file, It works,

```
system("cmd /C \"%HOMEPATH%\\AppData\\Roaming\\com.Project\\Local Store\\update.bat\"");
```

But I have 2 issues with this method :

- The CMD stays opened,
- The last version of the software stays frozen in the background, so the bat file is not closing it ...

All of this will disappear as soon as I close the new installed version of  the software ...

So should I try to improve the java program, find a way to implement it ? or is there a better way using the native extension ?

Can any one help me with this ? Thank you in advance

---

**EDIT**

For now, what I did is, I am using a simple vbs file that will run the batch file,

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "update.bat",0,True
```

and launch the vbs via the native extension, it's a quiet good result, but now I have a blank cmd during the execution which I'd like to hide ... a pretty exhausting workaround ...

I can work with this for sometime, but I really want to improve it ..

Comment: an alternative may be NativeProcess - it allows you to run CMD but you dont need to go thru an ANE. See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html

Comment: @LeeBurrows yep, I know that, but the commands will shut down the application, uninstall it, install the new version, and run it, so I can't really run CMD from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution for the freezing is to replace:

```
system("cmd /C \"%HOMEPATH%\\AppData\\Roaming\\com.Project\\Local Store\\update.bat\"");
```

with:

```
system("start cmd /C \"%HOMEPATH%\\AppData\\Roaming\\com.Project\\Local Store\\update.bat\"");
```

**EDIT**

To solve both issues you could avoid the batch file and execute the commands currently in your batch file directly from your native application using the [`ShellExecute` native API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The following should be placed in the native C application and should do what your batch file is currently doing (maybe some tuning will be needed). You will need to include the `windows.h` header in your application (`#include <windows.h>`).

```
    ShellExecute( NULL, "open", "taskkill.exe", "/IM Project.exe", NULL, SW_HIDE );
    ShellExecute( NULL, "open", "taskkill.exe", "/IM adl.exe", NULL, SW_HIDE );
    ShellExecute( NULL, "open", "wmic.exe", 
        "product where name=\"Project\" call uninstall /nointeractive", 
        NULL, SW_HIDE );
    ShellExecute( NULL, "open", 
        "%HOMEPATH%\\AppData\\Roaming\\com.Project\\Local Store\\Project.exe", 
        "-silent -eulaAccepted -location \"%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\" -desktopShortcut",  
        NULL, SW_HIDE );
    ShellExecute( NULL, "open", 
        "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\\Project\\Project.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_HIDE );
```

Note: for the sake of simplicity I didn't include error management code. If you want a robust application you should check the return value from `ShellExecute` to detect any error and act accordingly. See the `ShellExecute` docs.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the freezing, now when the cmd is still opened, it's in this line C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Project\Project.exe", it will run this command taskkill /IM cmd.exe only if I close the project, I tried the start before the command in the bat file, it will close the cmd, but open another one with the path for the .exe as a title ...

Comment: @KhalilBhm Depending on the command line quoting, `start` can get confused. Try `system("start \"\" cmd /C ...` note the empty pair of quotes just after `start`.

Comment: I know, I just tried it on the bat file, `start "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Project\Project.exe"` and adding `exit` but that will just open a new cmd as I told you, with the file's path as a title

Comment: In the batch you should write `start "" "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Project\Project.exe"`

Comment: @LorenzoDonatiThanks a lot for this solution, the thing is, if I run it this way, I'll delete it when I uninstall the application, cuz it's in it ... that's why I tried a bat file, keeping it in the appStorage, so it won't be affected while uninstalling, you see ?

Comment: The answer is just using this, and generating an .exe directly from the .bat file, thank you !